# How to get max value of total in dax

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have written below measure to get average inventory days

```
Inventory Days = 
VAR _Sales = SUM(FactStockAndSale[SaleQTY])
VAR _Closing = SUM(FactStockAndSale[Closing])
VAR _DaysInMonth = MAX(FactStockAndSale[DaysInMonth])
RETURN
_DaysInMonth*_Closing/_Sales
```

Which is working fine for me..and below is the result.

[image]

But then I want an extra column which should be the maximum value of every value which is grouped by Company and Month column.

means output should be as below.

[image]

Comment: You are showing us a max of 33.52 and 34.75, those values are not in January what so ever. I do not understand why the first 2 rows have a different max. Please change your sample so it is clear what we are looking at.

Comment: I did that in excel just to show the example.